# Capitalize Names in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which Capitalize the sentences. But its not able to Capitalize names such as,

```
D'agostino, Fred  
D'agostino, Ralph B.  
D'allonnes, C. Revault  
D'amanda, Christopher
```

I am expecting:

```
D'Agostino, Fred  
D'Agostino, Ralph B.  
D'Allonnes, C. Revault  
D'Amanda, Christopher
```

**Function**:

```
getCapitalized(str){
    var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;
    return str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\s-]*/g, function (match, index, title) {
      if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
        match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
        (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
        (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== "'" || title.charAt(index - 1) === "'") &&
        title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
        return match.toLowerCase();
      }
      if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
        return match;
      }
      return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
    });
  }
```

Can anybody help me figuring out the issue? I have tried using `(title.charAt(index + match.length) !== "'" || title.charAt(index - 1) === "'")` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Isn't the part of your code that tests for `'` currently only applied to things that match the `smallWords`?

Comment: Oh I see it now! Thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: @nnnnnn Do u have any optimal solution for this?

Comment: Optimal solution is: [leave names alone](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). There is no way to make a program that will handle all names correctly. Let the user input names as they want, and then don't touch them afterwards.

Comment: Never mind I found a solution for my question..
`str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\'\s-]*/g,` just added `\'` in regex array

Comment: What about names like John MacAuthor, DeTerro Vallez, or Mary John-Allen? How would someone detect those?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure about all the use-cases you need to take care of, but for the question you asked, you can use regex that looks for word boundaries:

```js
function capitalizeName(name) {
  return name.replace(/\b(\w)/g, s => s.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(capitalizeName(`D'agostino, Fred`));
console.log(capitalizeName(`D'agostino, Ralph B.`));
console.log(capitalizeName(`D'allonnes, C. Revault`));
console.log(capitalizeName(`D'amanda, Christopher`));
```

Comment: Does not work with special characters: with 'óscar álvarez' => 'óScar áLvarez'

Answer (score 4):

I use this function to capitalize names.
The parameter is usefult to force lowercase before capitalize otherwise you can get odd results (BaLlERinO, LaMbORGhini..)

It use regexp to find a space or a special character in ['`‘’.-]
followed by any character not in ASCII groups 0-97 and 123-223 because there are only symbols, numbers and uppercase letters, but this characther must not be followed by another space or end of string (to avoid results like Ciccio's )

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function (lower) {
  return (lower ? this.toLowerCase() : this).replace(/(?:^|\s|['`‘’.-])[^\x00-\x60^\x7B-\xDF](?!(\s|$))/g, function (a) {
    return a.toUpperCase();
  });
};

console.log(" ëkthor thörsen's örst'ûber o'brian von-fist's".capitalize(true))
// Ëkthor Thörsen's Örst'Ûber O'Brian Von-Fist's
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works with accented characters:

```
"d'agOstIno, jeAn-franÇois óscar álvarez".toLowerCase().replace(/[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+/g, (c) => c[0].toUpperCase() + c.substring(1))
```

Test it:

```html
<form>
  Input:<br />
  <textarea name="input" style="width: 500px" onchange="form.output.value=this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+/g, (c) => c[0].toUpperCase() + c.substring(1));" onkeyup="form.output.value=this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+/g, (c) => c[0].toUpperCase() + c.substring(1));">d'agOstIno, jeAn-franÇois-óscar álvarez</textarea><br />
  Output:<br />
  <textarea name="output" style="width: 500px" readonly onclick="select(this)">D'Agostino, Jean-François-Óscar Álvarez</textarea>
</form>
```

**=== OLD ANSWER : simpler but only for unaccented characters ===**

```
"d'agOstIno, jeAn-phI".toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase())
```

```html
<form>
  Input:<br />
  <textarea name="input" style="width: 500px" onchange="form.output.value=this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase())" onkeyup="form.output.value=this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase())">d'agOstIno, jeAn-phiLIpPE</textarea><br /> Output:
  <br />
  <textarea name="output" style="width: 500px" readonly onclick="select(this)">D'Agostino, Jean-Philippe</textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const correctTheName = (myName) => {
  const nameArray = myName.split(" ");
  const correctName = [];
  nameArray.forEach((item) => {
    const lowerCase = item.toLowerCase();
    const fLetter = lowerCase.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    const rletters = lowerCase.slice(1, lowerCase.length);
    const finalName = fLetter + rletters;
    correctName.push(finalName);
  });
  const theName = correctName.join(" ");
  console.log(theName);
};

correctTheName("pervez GHani MasiH");
correctTheName("pervez GHani MasiH shakeel");
correctTheName("elisha");
correctTheName("HaJi shakir ali makhdom chaudary malik");
```

Comment: This code does not work per the OP's input and output specifications.